# cant obtain all links from bookmark by Scrapy Selector

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I export a bookmark from chrome, and want to use `Scrapy Selector` to obtain all the links, but I can only get parts of the links (250 out of 650)

here is my code

```
html = r'C:\Users\super\Downloads\Desktop\temp\html\bookmarks_9_13_22.html'
xpath = r'//@href'
with open(html, 'rb') as f:
    source = f.read()
target = Selector(text=source).xpath(xpath).getall()
print(len(target))
```

Am I doing anything wrong? I am kind of new in scrapy and XPath.

here is the [bookmark (html file)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VwHmqdXSjJGMbz32hx1uhf4PaggOZbkt/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the unclosed `<DT>` tags in the file are causing the issue.

Solution:  remove the `<DT>` tags

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
html = open(r'C:\Users\super\Downloads\Desktop\temp\html\bookmarks_9_13_22.html', 'rb').read()
root = Selector(text=html.replace(b'<DT>',b''))
final = root.xpath("//@href").getall()
print(len(final))  # <--- 650
```

Comment: thank you, your way is working!!!  Could you suggest how you figure out this issue? No matter whether I print the HTML from python, or review it in Chrome, There is a lot of source code from my screen that I really have a hard time figuring out the `<TD>' tag causae this problem. Is it a common issue that's why you can figure out it easily? or you are using some tools that can highlight or display the source code in a clear way that let you search the elements easier?

Comment: @kai IDK if it is common, I have never seen Markup like this before. The way I discovered it was just from looking at the text in your google drive link, all of theose <DT> tags was one of the first things I noticed that looked out of place, so I copied the text and ran the code in my example and it worked.  The red flag was that none of the <DT> tags have a matching closing tag.

Comment: I see the way you work. Thank sharing it. I wonder if there is any way using XPath can detect the unclosed tags? The reason why I want to do it is because I always save some HTML from chrome, and using `Selector` and `xpath` to find my target elements. I can use the same `xpath` to find from the online content, but when saving into an offline HTML, it doesn't work at all, or I find fewer elements like the example in here.

Comment: I wonder the saved HTML from chrome always have some unclosed tags, and that cause a lot of problems. So if there is any way to detect the unclosed tags, it will be a great tool also.

Comment: @kai   make sure you use the @ symbol and the persons username when you are talking to them in the comments.  As far as I know there is no way to automatically detect unclosed tags. But this shouldn't be that common of a problem.  Like I said this was the first time I have ever come across it.

Comment: @Alxander I get it, thank for helping me out!!!

Comment: @kai your welcome... If that answers your question please mark the question as answered